# How to remove parentheses from year in Chicago style in natbib package?

Tags: natbib

I use `natbib` package and need to remove parentheses from year in Chicago style. Other questions in this site are not about `natbib` package. How should I do this? My codes are:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
  \usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
  \begin{document}

      \bibliography{references}
      \bibliographystyle{chicago}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: If you use `chicago`, why are you trying to change the recommended output?

Comment: @egreg: The [Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/ch14/ch14_sec016.html) says: "In a bibliography entry the elements are separated by periods [...]; the facts of publication are not enclosed in parentheses [...]". So `chicago` doesn't follow the recommendations of the Chicago Manual of Style here.

Answer (score 2):

- To remove the parentheses from the bibliography, save the `chicago.bst` file ([found here](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/chicago?lang=en)) under different name (maybe 'chicago2.bst'). Look for the year formatting function (`FUNCTION {output.year.check}`) and replace it with the following:

  ```
  FUNCTION {output.year.check}
     { year empty$
     { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$ }
     { write$
        " " year * extra.label *
       month empty$
       { }
        { ", " * month * }
     if$
     mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
    if$
   }
  ```

  Now use this file as your style file: `\bibliographystyle{chicago2}`.
- To remove the parentheses from the citations, you can use `\citealt` or other alternative commands. Check out [the reference sheet for `natbib`](http://ctan.um.ac.ir/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natnotes.pdf) (page 2, Suppressed parentheses). A snapshot from the reference sheet is given below.

  [image]

Comment: i mean remove parentheses in reference section in my article like:        author name, year,title     instead of    author name,(year), title

Comment: @faribamilani I've updated my answer to add this.